# Removing character from part of Email Address

Tags: php, email

Working with emails in PHP.
I want to remove all characters '.' from first part of email.
jo.hn.smith@yahoo.com should become: johnsmith@yahoo.com
The code I have removes also the '.' in yahoo.com.
This is my problem. I want to use preg_replace.
I need the regex for this.

Comment: Please post the code you have. This could be a relatively simple tweak of your existing regular expression.

Comment: Explode the string by `@` and then run your replace on the first array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look-ahead, i.e.:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\.(?=.*@)/', '', $email);
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1AL6Jr/1)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (Untested)

```
$str = 'jo.hn.smith@yahoo.com';

$res = explode('@', $str);

$res[0] = str_replace('.', '', $res[0]);

$str = implode('@', $res);
// $str = $res[0] . '@' . $res[1];
```

Splits the string into two and then runs the string replace on the first array value.

Then stick it all back together again

Comment: `implode()` needs two parameters